# MFC carchive to xml

Tags: xml, serialization, mfc

We have a legacy app that uses MFC's CArchive. I am researching saving the data in XML vs. binary. I have looked several libraries such as:

- Boost
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xmlize.aspx
- http://www.ucancode.net/faq/Visual-C-MFC-XML-Example.htm
- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c4567

They are nice, and offer many advantages above & beyond MFC's CArchive.

The main goal of the effort (other than an XML store) is to minimize code changes to this legacy app. I don't need new/improved serialization functionality for this project, and ideally, I could change a few CArchive objects to CXmlArchive and, like a puff of orange smoke, the store is XML.

Do you know of an existing library that meets the above requirements?